# Access Next Offset from GET http api request

Tags: json, http, parsing, pagination, offset

I'm unable to understand pagination of Chargebee (https://apidocs.chargebee.com/docs/api) , I need to create a request in where I can add next offset to the request to get further data (without setting limit other then by default, which is 10). But i'm unable to understand how http request will be formed with this given next_offset like attached image.

[Screenshot of request and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwrdE.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have had success submitting the identical request with the offset tacked onto the end.  Here is an example:

```
First Request

curl -s https://xxyyzz.chargebee.com/api/v2/events -G -K /home/xxyyzz/.cb_curl_key.cfg --data-urlencode limit=2 --data-urlencode occurred_at[between]="[1554076800,1554077099]"

JSON results:

{
    "list": [
        {"event": {
            "id": "ev_xxyyzz1",
            "occurred_at": 1554077022,
...
    "next_offset": "[\"1556428868000\",\"364450353\"]"
}

The tool I used to display the json is trying to be helpful with the backslashes.
The real next_offset value is

["1556428868000","364450353"]


Second Request

Identical to the first with 

offset="["1554077017000","345017569"]"

tacked on to the end:


curl -s https://xxyyzz.chargebee.com/api/v2/events -G -K /home/xxyyzz/.cb_curl_key.cfg --data-urlencode limit=2 --data-urlencode --data-urlencode occurred_at[between]="[1554076800,1554077099]" offset="["1554077017000","345017569"]"

JSON results:

{
    "list": [
        {"event": {
            "id": "ev_xxyyzz3",
            "occurred_at": 1556429028,
```

}

Keep repeating the process until the "next_offset" key does not appear in the JSON result.